# Prometheus /metrics page wasn't updated after the Counter was called

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, micrometer

I have a Spring Bean where the Gauges are initilized like that:

```
   @PostConstruct
    public void initGauge() {
        paymentsTriedGauge = Gauge.build().name("payments_tried").help("How many payments was sent to PaymentServices to be created").register(registry.getPrometheusRegistry());
        paymentsCreated = Gauge.build().name("payments_created").help("How many payments sent to PaymentServices were created").register(registry.getPrometheusRegistry());
    }
```

where the registry is from

```
@Autowired
PrometheusMeterRegistry registry;
```

and then in one method I do:

```
paymentsTriedGauge.inc();
```

but later on Promtheus's /metrics page I got no update:

```
# HELP payments_tried How many payments was sent to PaymentServices to be created
# TYPE payments_tried gauge
payments_tried 0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usecase is using Prometheus gauges directly. Micrometer itself can be used with its own [gauges](https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/gauges.html#_manually_incrementing_or_decrementing_a_gauge). (Spring Boot is not required)

For example:

```java
// maintain a reference to myGauge
AtomicInteger myGauge = registry.gauge("numberGauge", new AtomicInteger(0));

// ... elsewhere you can update the value it holds using the object reference
myGauge.set(27);
myGauge.set(11);
```

Notice the variable `myGauge` is actually an `AtomicInteger` and Micrometer is just reporting the value of that instance. `AtomicInteger` also has an `increment()` method you can use fine.

Answer (score -1):

To make it working properly I have to initialize the variables as `Counter` and use

```
paymentsTriedGauge = Counter.build().name("payments_tried").help("How many payments was sent to PaymentServices to be created").register(registry.getPrometheusRegistry());
```

instead of `Gauge`.

With `Gauge` it is compiled and doesn't fail, but is't updated on `.inc()`.

Comment: A gauge is typically pointing at another value (the size of a list for example) or being set to a value. The `inc()` behavior sounds incorrect. Also don't use Prometheus directly. Stick with the Micrometer abstractions: `registry.gauge...`

Comment: @checketts unfortunately, this is not Spring Boot, so have to use directly. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Ok. I'll expand it into a full answer for.you